# Keyboard issue for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I have a `Dialog` in which I am having a `EditText`.
Issues which I am facing are:

1). When `Dialog` is shown at that moment Keyboard does not come itself. So I had to programmatically bring keyboard up.

```
InputMethodManager immOnResume = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                                        Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        immOnResume.showSoftInput(mEditText,
                                InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

2). When pressing home button keyboard is still visible in Home screen. I think as I am programmatically bringing keyboard up then I have to programmatically hide keyboard.

```
InputMethodManager immN = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    immN.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                            mEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

But these also isn't working.
Any suggestions how can I solve my issue.

Comment: The keyboard is not disappearing because you used `InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED`. You should use `InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: what about if I press home button.

Comment: Nothing. Please try it this way first. In my case, I am handling an Activity with Dialog-Theme and the keyboard is hidden on pressing home button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `myedittext.requestFocus()`

The keyboard will automatically vanish when activity is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

If your UI is written in XML, you might consider adding the requestFocus tag:

```
<EditText ...>
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

That should trigger the focus on your EditText field when your dialog opens, which in turn should open your keyboard.

If, however, your UI is done programatically

```
editText.requestFocus()
```